# Line Not Found in Java

Tags: java, file

Im having trouble reading data from a file. The error that i receive is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Driver.readFile(Driver.java:20)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:9)
```

I don't understand why the line isn't found when there are clearly more. My professor said to clear the buffer by making a temporary variable to hold the new line after the last line was read (*String temp*). I still get the same error. Clarity would be appreciated. Sorry for the long post in advanced. Wanted to show all work to help everyone understand my issue.

***Here is my Driver class:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pets [] pets = new Pets[25];
    
    int numPets = readFile(pets);
    System.out.println(numPets);
    
}
public static int readFile(Pets [] pets) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner("pets.dat");
    
    int count = 0;
    while (kb.hasNext()) {
        
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        String owner = kb.nextLine();
        String species = kb.nextLine();
        String breed = kb.nextLine();
        double age = kb.nextDouble();
        double weight = kb.nextDouble();
        String temp = kb.nextLine();
        
        Pets pet = new Pets(name, owner, species, breed, age, weight);
        pets [count] = pet;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

***Here is my Pets class if needed:***

```
public class Pets {

private String name;
private String owner;
private String species;
private String breed;
private double age;
private double weight;

Pets() {
    
}
Pets(String name, String owner, String species, String breed, double age, double weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.species = species;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
    
}
boolean isSpecies(String species) {
    if (this.species == species) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Owner: " + owner + "\n" + "Species: " + species + "\n" + "Breed: " + breed + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n"  + "Weight: "+ weight;
}
}
```

***Here is the data file:***

```
Izzy
Liz Davidson
cat
domestic shorthair
2
10.5
Duncan
Sofia Berrios
dog
basset hound
9
56
Otis Redding
Scott Grasso
hamster
golden
0.5
0.1
Guinness
Kumar Chaudhuri
dog
mutt
6
32
Snape
Liping Xiang
snake
grass snake
3.5
0.5
Artemis
Ali Khan
cat
domestic shorthair
11
12
KD
Rachel Kauffman
dog
Akita
6
65
Morgan
Nick McEntire
cat
Russian blue
.8
8.4
Max
Kelly Luiselli
dog
mutt
15
38
Ingrid
Terry Dumas
snake
boa constrictor
3.5
4.6
```

Comment: Is that really your data file, e.g., without the last line of text? Your scanners don't seem to align with the data.

Comment: The problem is you're using the wrong `Scanner` constructor. Your first `nextLine` call is returning the string "pets.dat". It's not opening a file called "pets.dat".  Try `new File("pets.dat")` instead of `pets.dat`. And get rid of the `temp` call as it will gobble up the next `name`. FYI, if you had printed `name` after getting it, you would have seen the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few little things need to be changed in your code. Below is your code with my corrections. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File source = new File("pets.dat");
        List<Pets> list = new ArrayList<Pets>();
        try (Scanner kb = new Scanner(source)) {
            while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
                String name = kb.nextLine();
                String owner = kb.nextLine();
                String species = kb.nextLine();
                String breed = kb.nextLine();
                String ageStr = kb.nextLine();
                double age = Double.parseDouble(ageStr);
                String weightStr = kb.nextLine();
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(weightStr);
                Pets pet = new Pets(name, owner, species, breed, age, weight);
                list.add(pet);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("count = " + list.size());
    }
}

class Pets {
    private String name;
    private String owner;
    private String species;
    private String breed;
    private double age;
    private double weight;

    Pets() {
        
    }
    Pets(String name, String owner, String species, String breed, double age, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.species = species;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        
    }
    boolean isSpecies(String species) {
        if (this.species == species) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Owner: " + owner + "\n" + "Species: " + species + "\n" + "Breed: " + breed + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n"  + "Weight: "+ weight;
    }
}
```

Since your problem is reading the file, I simply wrote a `main()` method to demonstrate how you should read the file.

Note that the `while` loop condition is `kb.hasNextLine()` and not `kb.hasNext()`. Your data file contains one item of data per line. Hence you need to read a line at a time. That's why I only call method `nextLine()` inside the `while` loop. You need to read a line and handle it. Hence I initially read the line that contains a `double` as a string and then convert that string to a double. And I removed this line from your code:

```java
String temp = kb.nextLine();
```

It is not required. I think your Professor was trying to tell you to read the *age* and the *weight* as strings and then convert each string to a double, as I have done. That's why he suggested the temporary variable.

Also I store the `Pets` in a `List` rather than an array because there is no limit (theoretically) to how many elements a `List` may contain.

Also it is important to close the data file once you have read all of its contents. That's why I use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).